# Can't pinpoint FBSDKGraphRequest crash

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform

I'm using FB Login, and my app is crashing every now and then within that method. It works fine for me, but not for some other users. In this function, I'm setting user data in Parse with data received from the `FBSDKGraphRequest`.

```
// Sends FB Graph Request and sets user attributes in Parse
    func setUserData() {

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()!

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                println("Set user values error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {

                firstName = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! NSString
                lastName = result.valueForKey("last_name") as! NSString
                user["name"] = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("\(firstName) \(lastName)", forKey: "name")

                id = result.valueForKey("id") as! NSString
                user["fbID"] = id

                gender = result.valueForKey("gender") as! NSString
                user["gender"] = gender

                email = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
                user["email"] = email

                user["score"] = 100

                user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        objID = user.objectId!
                    }
                })
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: self)
            }

        })

    }
```

Now, in Crashlytics, I'm getting `EXC_BREAKPOINT`, but can't figure out exactly where the crash is coming from or what to do about it. Looks like it may be coming from Facebook's side? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I would start by printing what's on the result. It seems like the crash happens when the Facebook SDK is calling your completion handler.

Comment: @corvuszero I can't read the logs of that user's crash though. It's crashing at the closing bracket of the FBSDKGraphRequest function. And I am handling the error with `if error != nil`, so idk why this is crashing and freezing

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same issue. I forgot to put the permissions on the FBSDKLoginButton:

```
    facebookLoginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"];
```

Maybe you forgot it too?

Comment: Oh, BTW. Your users have to log in again, for the changes to have an effect.